# React:I have to pick either date ranges over months or time ranges for single day

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker, react-datetime

React: I have to select the date ranges or time range ON A SINGLE DAY

Have date and time range but want to check either date range or time range for a single day. Which means if you select date range, have to disable to time selection where as if you want to check for a single day we have to pass the time ranges.

```
    import React from "react";
    import {render} from "react-dom";
    import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";

    class Datepick extends React.Component {
        state = {
            startDate: new Date(),
            endDate: new Date()
        };

        handleStartChange = startDate => {
            this.setState({startDate});
            this.to.openCalendar();
        };

        handleEndChange = endDate => {
                return this.setState({endDate});
        };

        render() {
            const {startDate, endDate} = this.state;
            return (
                <div style={{height: "100vh"}}>
                <span>
                    <DatePicker
                        onChange={this.handleStartChange}
                        value={startDate}
                        showLeadingZeroes={true}
                        minDate={new Date()}
                    />
                </span>
                    <span>
                    <DatePicker
                        ref={el => (this.to = el)}
                        onChange={this.handleEndChange}
                        value={endDate}
                        showLeadingZeroes={true}
                        minDate={new Date()}
                        />
                    </span>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

    export default Datepick;
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is? Also it seems like it's not really about react is it? (according to the codepen you posted)

Comment: @Ahmad I have to develop an date picker in react where it either  picks an date range or time range, when it picks an time range it should be restricted to the particular day and disable the date range